# Store string output as variable and put in message of an email

Tags: python, string, email, variables

I have a code snippet that looks like this:

```
for flt in fa_flts:
  dates = FAT.loc[FAT['Flight Number'] == flt, 'Scheduled Departure Date'].to_string(index = False)
  dep = FAT.loc[FAT['Flight Number'] == flt, 'Departure Station'].unique().item()
  arr = FAT.loc[FAT['Flight Number'] == flt, 'Arrival Station'].unique().item()
  print(f'For AA{flt} {dep}{arr}, the dates flight attendants are on a turn are: \n{dates}')
  print('\n')
  
for flt in pi_flts:
  dates = PIT.loc[PIT['Flight Number'] == flt, 'Scheduled Departure Date'].to_string(index = False)
  dep = PIT.loc[PIT['Flight Number'] == flt, 'Departure Station'].unique().item()
  arr = PIT.loc[PIT['Flight Number'] == flt, 'Arrival Station'].unique().item()
  print(f'For AA{flt} {dep}{arr}, the dates pilots are on a turn are: \n{dates}') 
  print('\n')
```

This outputs a statement, or a message, that I want to package up and send in an email. Right now my email code snippet looks like this:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import pandas as pd

##############################################################################
#Parameters for Email
msg = MIMEMultipart()
subject = "YUL Crew Transits For Next Month" 

email_body = ?????

file_name = "Vax"

#Separated by semicolon
sender = "*****@example.com"
recipients = ["*****@example.com"]


############################################################################

msg = ??????

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtpdc.aa.com:25")
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()

msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ",".join(recipients)

server.sendmail(sender, recipients , msg.as_string())
server.close()
```

I know I have to put something in the ???? area. I want the output of the for loops to go into the body of the email. I have tried creating a function that prints the output and then calling the function in the msg variable, but this causes NoneType error. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Change the `for` loops to concatenate the strings into a variable instead of printing.

Comment: `msg = f'...'` instead of `print(f'...')`

Comment: I have tried this but when I go into the snippet with the email, I cannot set msg equal to that variable. I get the error message 'str' object does not support item assignment'

Comment: I thought `msg` was just the body of the message. It looks like you intend it to be a dictionary, but there's no `.as_string()` method of dictionaries.

Comment: Put the message body and headers in separate variables, then concatenate them.

Comment: It seems like you're expecting there to be a method that turns the dictionary into email headers. There's nothing built-in that does this AFAIK. You need to format the header yourself.

Comment: What dictionary? There is no dictionary

Comment: `msg['Subject'] = subject` is assigning to the `Subject` element of a dictionary in the `msg` variable.